# Pass multiple variables from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to pass multiple variables from controller to view in codeigniter?

This is my controller:

```
function viewmembers(){
            $this->load->model('UsersModel');
            $data['students'] = $this->UsersModel->studentlist_all();
            $data['user'] = $this->UsersModel->select_admin($id);
            $this->load->view('portal/viewstudents', $data);
    }
```

And here is my view:

```
    foreach($user as $user_select){
                            $id = $user_select['USERNAME']; 
                            $fname = $user_select['FNAME'];
                            $mname = $user_select['MNAME'];
                            $lname = $user_select['LNAME'];
                            $nick = $user_select['NICK'];
                            }
    echo $nick;
```

It gives me "undefined variable: nick".

I also tried
print_r($user), but it gives me a value "Array()"

althought print_r($students) works

Comment: i think you have fetch `result` instead of `row` in model . Can you please post your model method `select_admin($id)` ??

Comment: public function select_admin($id){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('admins');
        $this->db->where('USERNAME',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

Answer (score 0):

`result_array()` will not return single row. If you want single row then you should use `row_array()` . Also,in your `where condition` you are trying to match `username` field against `id`, it is wrong .So, your method must be as below :

```
public function select_admin($id){
     $this->db->select('*');
     $this->db->from('admins'); 
    $this->db->where('id',$id); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->row_array();
     }
```

And to echo the field value in your view :

```
echo $user['your_field_value_name'];
```

If you want to explore more then see this [doc](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Comment: You do not have to loop the `$data['user']` value in view now. `echo $user['your_filed_name']` should work buddy .

Comment: can you please post the value of `print_r($data['user'])`; ??

Comment: Just prints as "Array ( )"

Comment: In you where condition you are doing `where('USERNAME',$id); ` is it right ? you are trying to match username with  `id` . I think there should be `id` instead of username.